# Replacing value of specific pixel using raster mask in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have two rasters: the first is a basin with all pixels values equal to 0. The second raster (mask) has a single pixel with value = 1. In fact, I need only one raster where all the pixels into the basin must be = 0 and this specific pixel (in the mask) must have the value 1.

How can I do this process using ArcGIS Desktop?

I tried to use raster calculator with the sum "Raster 1 + Raster 2", but it did not work because the result is all the pixels into the basin equal to 1.

Comment: I provided a quick answer, assuming that the mask covers all null values in the basin raster, but does your mask layer need to exclude additional areas in the basin? I can update to reflect that.

Comment: Many thanks, SaultDon. The mask doesn't cover all the pixels in the basin raster. The mask is just a isolated pixel and I'm tryng to use this pixel to change the value in the corresponding pixel at the basin raster.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. I used Cell Statistics instead Raster Calculator and checked the box "ignore no data". :)

Comment: You can post that as an answer to and mark as correct. Helps anyone else with the same problem find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

What I did:

I used Cell Statistics (instead Raster Calculator). The tool allow you to do the sum (or any other operation) ignoring 'No data' values in the mask raster, so the others pixels in the main raster are not affected.

Answer (score 1):

`Con(IsNull("basin"),"mask","basin")`

After re-reading your question more carefully looks like the above does exactly that.

What it does is use the `Con()` function with an embedded `IsNull()` function.

The format looks like:
`Con(look for this value, if found make it this, else this)`

So in your case look at the Null Values in basin, where they exist - fill em in with mask, else if they aren't null in basin leave them as basin.